# Problemas con el emulador se queda en blanco

Tags: android-studio

amigos del foro esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, les cuento que el día de ayer el emulador funcionaba muy bien y el tablet y celular, y hoy día al hacerlo correr se queda en blanco la pantalla, investigue que ocupe el clean proyect y después el rebuild, despues la memoria cache, limpie el equipo también, elimine el emulador y lo volvi a instalar, en el sdkmaneger lo actualice con lo que solicitaba y nada, ahora les dejo realice un debug con el celular y me arrojo esto:

```
05/04 17:17:09: Launching 'app' on samsung SM-A217M.
Install successfully finished in 757 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.prueba/com.example.prueba1.MainActivity" -a 
android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.prueba
Connecting to com.example.prueba
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the

"Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/.example.prueb: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on 
this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication()++ app=com.example.prueba
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10288; state: ENABLED
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.prueba is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:53639', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1359)
W/ActivityThread: Slow operation: 3221ms so far, now at handleBindApplication: Before
 HardwareRenderer
W/ActivityThread: Slow operation: 3246ms so far, now at handleBindApplication: After HardwareRenderer
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~lPll-UBAAjFsp_XvDPDcCQ==/com.example.prueba-
Yqe1wn_31h81JMGA03KJ9w==/base.dm': No such file or directory
/nativeloader: Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /data/app/~~lPll-UBAAjFsp_XvDPDcCQ==/com.example.prueba-Yqe1wn_31h81JMGA03KJ9w==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~lPll-UBAAjFsp_XvDPDcCQ==/com.example.prueba-Yqe1wn_31h81JMGA03KJ9w==/lib/arm64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.example.prueba
V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.example.prueba' set to: 'default'
V/GraphicsEnvironment: Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
D/LoadedApk: LoadedApk::makeApplication() appContext.mOpPackageName=com.example.prueba
appContext.mBasePackageName=com.example.prueba
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication() --
D/OpenGLRenderer: RenderThread::requireGlContext()
D/hw-ProcessState: Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
D/OpenGLRenderer: RenderThread::setGrContext()
D/AppCompatDelegate: Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
I/DecorView: [INFO] isPopOver=false, config=true
I/DecorView: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@249ba04[], isFloating=false, isApplication=true, 
hasWindowControllerCallback=true, hasWindowDecorCaption=false
D/DecorView: setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@249ba04[]
I/DecorView: getCurrentDensityDpi: from real metrics. densityDpi=280 msg=resources_loaded
W/.example.prueb: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;-
>computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/.example.prueb: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10288; state: ENABLED
W/.example.prueb: Verification of androidx.fragment.app.Fragment 
com.example.prueba1.Controlador.PagerController.getItem(int) took 155.842ms (320.84 bytecodes/s) 
(2688B approximate peak alloc)
I/ViewRootImpl@35bdec7[MainActivity]: setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@249ba04 TM=true
D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
I/.example.prueb: Compiler allocated 4148KB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>
(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
```

ojala que me puedan ayudar porque no entiendo en que estoy mal, si el equipo, porqué la codificación está bien no arroja ningún error, incluso lo que hoce el día de hoy lo deje en comentario pensando que era eso el error, desde ya muchas gracias y disculpen las molestias.

esto es el logcat que me arroja:

```
`2023-05-04 17:59:30.879 1893-1893/? E/UsbPortManager: connectToProxy: usb` 
hal service not found. Did the service fail to start?
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at android.os.HwBinder.getService(Native Method)
    at android.os.HwBinder.getService(HwBinder.java:91)
    at android.hardware.usb.V1_0.IUsb.getService(IUsb.java:48)
    at android.hardware.usb.V1_0.IUsb.getService(IUsb.java:52)
    at com.android.server.usb.UsbPortManager.connectToProxy(UsbPortManager.java:531)
    at com.android.server.usb.UsbPortManager.<init>(UsbPortManager.java:137)
    at com.android.server.usb.UsbService.<init>(UsbService.java:142)
    at com.android.server.usb.UsbService$Lifecycle.onStart(UsbService.java:73)
    at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:126)
    at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:113)
    at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:72)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.startOtherServices(SystemServer.java:1299)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:431)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
```

ojala que sea de ayuda también.